# Fabric JS animation lag after a little while

Tags: animation, fabricjs, lag, requestanimationframe

I have a little issue with FabricJS.

I have animated a triangle, but the problem is that after a little while, it starts to seriously lag. I am a beginner, so I am not saying my code is the best way to do it, but I can't actually get rid of this lag. Any suggestion to fix this issue would be awesome.

Here is the fiddle: http://bit.ly/1kHlInC

Thanks

Comment: Actually I did not even thought about our lovely new technologies. I did it with CSS3 animations and it works perfectly! I guess I will stick with it for the time being.Thanks anyway! Also I let the topic open as I am still keen to know more about the issue I had.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  Your question seems to mix two different questions together--there's the issue of why your current Fiddle slows with time, and then there's the issue of how to use `requestAnimationFrame()`.  You'll get the best reponse by asking each of these seperately.

Comment: yeah you are right. I will remove the requestAnimationFrame part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with Fabric before, so I can't speak to the more detailed question on `requestAnimationFrame()`.  However, for your lag issue, your `onComplete()` callbacks are spawning an exponential number of animation calls--every loop of the triangle is calling excessive number of animation steps.

The issue is that when you need to animate in a diagonal manner you combine two `animate()` calls, such as `animate('left')` and `animate('top')`.  Both of these calls have an `onComplete()` callback calling the same next-step, however you only need to call this once.

Here's an updated fiddle which has been reorganized just enough to solve the issue by removing the extra callbacks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Uwaa8/2/

Comment: Amazing! thank you a lot for these explanations! it's all good now ;)

Comment: fwiw, `animate` accepts an object with multiple properties to animate (and makes sure to invoke callbacks only once), so that's another way to do this.